# Add to Request in Laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel's built in authentication and am adding on the birthday. I have multiple select fields that have the Month Day and Year. I want to combine these in RegisterUsers.php **postRegister** method to make a php readable date and pass it to the validation in the AuthController. I was thinking

```
$request['date'] = strtotime($request['month'] . $request['day'] . $request['year']);
```

and then continue with the request. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Also, I want to validate the date. What validate parameters can I use in the validate function? I want it so you can't enter April 31 as a birthday because there is only 30 days in April.

Comment: Validation rule : date

The field under validation must be a valid date according to the strtotime PHP function. OR date_format:format

The field under validation must match the format defined according to the date_parse_from_format PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nesbot's carbon package for dates and it's related stuff
[carbon.nesbot.com](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)